# Compiling python3 code in terminal with interpreter

Tags: command-line, python, compiling, python3

When I compile my code simply with the command `python3 name.py`, it's being run, but then the whole story ends and I can't do anything with the compiled data.

I want to somehow compile my program to the interpreter and have the ability to experiment with the data in that interpreter. For example, I want to use `timeit(function(argument))` with the function and the argument, defined and set in my name.py program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `-i` switch. According to the manpages:

```
-i    When  a  script  is passed as first argument or the -c option is
      used, enter interactive mode after executing the script  or  the
      command.  It does not read the $PYTHONSTARTUP file.  This can be
      useful to inspect global variables  or  a  stack  trace  when  a
      script raises an exception.
```

So if your script name is `name.py` what you need to do is run:

```
python3 -i name.py
```

Answer (score 0):

@daltonfury42's answer is one way to do it, but note that it will run the script first before going into the interpreter. Another one is to just run the interpreter in the same directory as your script and import it.

```
$ cat spam.py 
def main(*args):
    print("Called main() with args: ", args)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main("foo")
$ python3 spam.py 
Called main() with args:  ('foo',)
$ python3
>>> import spam
>>> spam.main("bar")
Called main() with args:  ('bar',)
>>>
```